# Are Servlet Init parameters accessible in whole servlet container

Tags: java, servlets

I have this question as i did not find any correct results when searching in Web.

Does Servlet Init Parameters y default accessible in whole container without making any configaration.I mean servlet A has some property x,If another servlet B ,in the same container(may be or may not be in same Application) access it? If so can anyone please show me with an example.

Thanks in Avance.

Answer (score 1):

No, init parameters are servlet-scoped, context-param are application scoped. 
There's no other wider scope (e.g. between two applications)

Comment: Also one more question on the same,If i change any of the init parameters for a servlet,changeswont be reflected until i restart the container right?

Comment: Yes, that's right...those parameters (and in general all what is in web.xml) is read at startup, deploy or redeploy time.

Comment: why do we need string init param to just use it in a servlet !? can some one refere me with an answer special thanks

Comment: Definitely a strange question ;) why do you need configuration files? Why do you need parameters in a method? The answer is moreless the same

Answer (score 0):

As servlet config, `The init parameters of a servlet can only be accessed by that servlet`
here is link http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/web-xml.html#initParams

Comment: why do we need string init param to just use it in a servlet !? can some one refere me with an answer special thanks